# Execute action if Wait-Process times out

Tags: powershell

If a process does not complete withing X amount of seconds, I want to execute some code (including killing that process). How can I do this?

Below is my current attempt. The problem here is that the code in the catch clause is never executed, even when the process times out.

```
$process = Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList "/k process.bat && exit" -PassThru
try {
    Wait-Process $process.Id -Timeout 3
}
catch {
    "Stopping process"
    Stop-Process $process
}
```

Comment: hitting the timeout is not an error. [*grin*] plus, you did not use `-ErrorAction Stop` to force a terminal error.

Comment: `-ErrorAction Stop` solved it. Thanks! If only they would document it ...

Comment: I usually set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` at the beginning of the script, so errors won't go unnoticed (it replaces `-ErrorAction` parameter). In rare cases, where I actually expect something to fail I pass `-ErrorAction Continue` and check `$?` for error.

Comment: @birgersp - you are most welcome! glad to help ... and they did document it. [*grin*] look at >>> `Get-Help about_CommonParameters` <<< & >>> `Get-Help about_Preference_Variables` <<< ///// it is sad that the help for `Wait-Process` doesn't _directly_ mention it, tho. it just says `[<CommonParameters>]`. [*sigh ...*]